# sequelize => why can't exclude come attributes from being returned while i am including other associated table

Tags: sequelize.js

sequelize => why can't exclude come attributes from being returned while I am including another associated table

```
trips = await travelRequests.findAll({
                    where: {
                        manager: email
                    },
                    attributes: {
                        exclude: [ 'userID', 'passportNumber', 'gender', 'createdAt', 'updatedAt' ]
          },
          include: [{
            model: Comments,
            attributes: {
              exclude: ['id', 'requestId' ]
            }
          }],
                    offset: pagination.offset,
                    limit: pagination.limit
                });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fetched same problem, I solved that by [Scope](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/scopes.html), Hope you can also solve your problem